# Does composer only reference classes and discard other code?

Tags: php, composer-php

With regards to dependencies within composer files, for example if I used a `classmap` to include the files, I notice an autoload file generated for example such as this:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'BBCode' => $vendorDir . '/cyphix333/nbbc/nbbc.php',
    'BBCodeEmailAddressValidator' => $vendorDir . '/cyphix333/nbbc/nbbc.php',
    'BBCodeLexer' => $vendorDir . '/cyphix333/nbbc/nbbc.php',
    'BBCodeLibrary' => $vendorDir . '/cyphix333/nbbc/nbbc.php',
);
```

Now, from what I can tell this is pointing to where it can find all the needed classes; but what if the file also has other code in it such as `CONSTANTS` set that the classes below it relies upon?

Is non-class code discarded or how does it work?

Comment: composer also recognises a `files` load directive

Comment: @MarkBaker Yeah, but how do you make sure that file is included **before** the other files that depend on the constants?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the `files` directive automatically loads all of the listed files immediately on startup, so they're always loaded (whether needed or not) before anything else that's autoloaded

Comment: At least this would make sense since there is no way for composer to detect which class requires which extra file - AFAIK. Probably you can try to post a feature request as this could make sense is some (rare?) cases

Comment: Hmmmmm...... well I just ran some tests and it seems the constants *do* exist. The constants are defined at the top of the `nbbc.php` file and they output the correct values when tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is non-class code discarded or how does it work?

No, it's not discared.
What you see is the generated classmap autoloaded.
It's a class to file mapping. The classnames are extracted from the file.
If a file contains multiple classes, then these classes are extracted and point to the same file. That's done to allow individual usage of these classes.

- If you use the `autoload.files` directive, then Composer will include the files on each request. They are always loaded.
- The order of the definition decides what's first. So, if your code has bootstrap code, like Constants, which affects code and "files" coming after the bootstrap, then position it at the top of the files section.
- It's better to use `autoload.classmap` directive to have real autoloading (when using the classname, load the file). Try this:

  ```
  "autoload": {
       "classmap": ["nbbc.php", "src/"]
  }
  ```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for all your help with composer.

Comment: You are welcome. (It's not easy to get old and legacy code running with Composer. Not only the Setup phase is complicated, but also the usage.)